# NVIDIA 525 driver spam journal/log

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I discovered a strange behavior today. While searching for the reason why my system shows every boot the file system check screen for 3-5 seconds I noticed that the new Nvidia 525 display driver, that I installed yesterday, write every second the following lines into the journal:

```
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VG248 (DFP-0): connected
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VG248 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VG248 (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Ancor Communications Inc VG248 (DFP-0): supports NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Mär 22 10:40:40 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

And this every second. I don't know how it was before because I noticed it just today while I'm remotely connected with my PC via AnyDesk. The Xorg Process also writes every second. I will quit this so safe SSD health.

I also found the following line in the latest log:

```
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (51, 162); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (WW) NVIDIA: Failed to bind sideband socket to
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (WW) NVIDIA:     '/var/run/nvidia-xdriver-e7399651' Permission denied
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (II) NVIDIA: Reserving 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (II) NVIDIA:     access.
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3120]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0:1920x1080_144+0+374,DVI-D-0:nvidia-au>
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes dbus-daemon[3075]: [session uid=1000 pid=3075] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMo>
Mär 22 07:56:41 johannes systemd[3060]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
```

SysInfo

- Type: Gaming PC
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (5.15.0-67-generic)
- Nvidia Driver: 525.85.12 (nvidia-graphics-drivers-525-server) installed from Ubuntu repo

Edit #1: Now I'm home and the Nvidia journal spam is over. Hmm... Is it maybe an AnyDesk-Thing?